# Heartbeat cluster - issue resource(httpd) migration back to primary

Tags: heartbeat

We have given the following setting with corosync and pacemaker.

```
crm configure rsc_defaults resource-stickiness="100"
```

And it works fine when the primary server goes down. But it wont work revers, resource(httpd) migration back to primary after restarting the primary and bringing down the secondary.

ie

As I said everything works well, but i need just one thing, i have the
directive " resource-stickiness="100", when node1 is down, the node2
starts all resources and prevent  failback again though the node1 is up,
 back i need move all resources to the first one when I certainly sure the
node1 is runnig, is there some directive to tell pacemaker that move back
again the to node1 automatically? i mean, is posibble to move back resources
to node1 when It has passed certain time, maybe 1 hour or something?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting the stickiness to 100, make it INFINITY and try this command

```
crm configure rsc_defaults resource-stickiness="INFINITY"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the  stickiness  INFINITY and try. Also create a new key on the secondary server which allow  with that key to log in to primary server.